# href me descarga un arhivo php en lugar de abrir en el navegador

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente menu creado. En la etiqueta "a" el "href" en lugar de abrirme el archivo php me lo descarga. ¿Porque puede estar sucediendo? ya probe abrirlo desde localhost y funciona todo bien. También probre crear en forma independiente un php y me meuestra el texto sin problemas. Es desde el html que no me funciona el hipervinculo...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Menu desplegable</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="menu">
        <section class="menu__container">
            <h1 class="menu__logo">ISFDHS -148</h1>
            <ul class="menu__links">
                <li class="menu__item">
                    <a href="index.html" class="menu__link">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item menu__item--show">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__link">Matrícula<img src="assets/arrow.svg" class="menu__arrow"></a>
                    <ul class="menu__nesting">
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="/alta.php" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Alta</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Baja</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Actualización</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Reportes</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item  menu__item--show">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__link">Mesas de exámenes<img src="assets/arrow.svg" class="menu__arrow"></a>
                        <ul class="menu__nesting">
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Resumenes de mesas</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Inscricpciones</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__inside">
                            <a href="#" class="menu__link menu__link--inside">Consula</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu__hamburguer">
                <img src="assets/menu.svg" class="menu__img">
            </div>
        </section>
    </nav>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parece ser un problema del servidor web, cual usas?

Comment: Hola Paola. Parece que falta algún dato en tu pregunta. La primera, que servidor usas y aunque para esta pregunta no sea necesario, es una buena costumbre indicar la versión de php. La segunda duda es si el problema es que se te descarga el archivo al hacer click en alguno de los enlaces de este mismo archivo o es al intentar cargar desde otra pagina este archivo. Si es esto ultimo, muy posiblemente no tengas el archivo dentro de la carpeta htdocs (o similar) de apache, no este corriendo apache, o no este corriendo php.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Estoy usando Xampp v3.3.3, Apache y mysql estan corriendo sin problemas. Lo que sucede es que se me descarga el archivo cuando hago clic sobre el enlace, es decir, en lugar de abrir otra seccion del sitio me descarga el archivo php. Me funciona en otros proyectos peor en este no.... El archivo esta dentro de htdocs, y a su vez dentro de otra carpeta con los archivos del proyecto. Probe cambiar el nombre de la extension del .html a .php y me funciona...

Comment: Añadiendo AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm en tu fichero .htaccess deberías poder usar html y htm como ficheros php. El problema que tienes es que apache te está devolviendo los ficheros html sin interpretarlos con php. La opción que te sugiero se puede hacer de otras formas, por ejemplo, editando los ficheros de configuración del propio apache. Si necesitas más ayuda al respecto, busca en google por "apache handler html php" sin las comillas.